# перехват сообщений

Tags: android

есть стороннее приложение в которое приходят сообщения новости. Есть ли возможность перехватывать эти сообщения, чтоб реагировать на них(нажать что новость прочитана)? Подскажите какую информацию почитать чтоб написать приложение которое будет следить за этим.

Comment: Ставишь приложение на телефон или виртуальное устройство, проксируешь траф через свой прокси сервер, там уже отлавливаешь нужные запросы и реагируешь на них.